# How do you trigger AD token expiration using azure blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to find the behavior of azure blob storage with AD authentication when uploading took more than 90 min for a single big file, unfortunately my internet is quite fast and my disk can't fit TB scale file, so I am trying to simulate slow upload

I tried the following code

```
import os
from io import BufferedReader, FileIO


class ProgressFile(BufferedReader):
    # For binary opening only

    def __init__(self, filename, read_callback):
        f = FileIO(file=filename, mode='r')
        self._read_callback = read_callback
        super().__init__(raw=f)

        # I prefer Pathlib but this should still support 2.x
        self.length = os.stat(filename).st_size

    def read(self, size=None):
        calc_sz = size
        if not calc_sz:
            calc_sz = self.length - self.tell()
        self._read_callback(position=self.tell(), read_size=calc_sz, total=self.length)
        return super(ProgressFile, self).read(size)

def my_callback(position, read_size, total):
    if position > 0 and position <= 4194304:
       time.sleep(5520)
    print("position: {position}, read_size: {read_size}, total: {total}".format(position=position,
                                                                                read_size=read_size,
                                                                                total=total))


myfile = ProgressFile(filename='./testfile', read_callback=my_callback)

from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
token_credential = ClientSecretCredential(
)

container_client = ContainerClient(oauth_url, "containername", token_credential)


def upload(filename):
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client("myfile")
    blob_client.upload_blob(myfile, blob_type="BlockBlob")
    print("finish uploading")

upload(int(time.time()))
```

However I don't see token expire error, even after 90 min

In what circumstance does token expiration appears?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential, it renews the token when it is close to expiration.

(I work in Microsoft Azure SDK team)

Comment: what happens if there is a big file that is getting uploaded that took longer than default token expiration 60-90min ?

Comment: It looks to me the storage library splits the payload into small trunks and upload them separately. Each one should finish within the token expiration limit.